# custom redirection only for special format via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

hi there I want a custom redirect via htaccess.

for only this format

```
www.example.com/index.php?id=abc --> www.example.com/abc
```

but for any other format no change:

for example

```
www.example.com/index.php?id=abc&id2=qaz --> www.example.com/index.php?id=abc&id2=qaz
```

This code (by @starkeen) do it great:

```
RewriteEngine on

#1)Redirect "/index.php?id=foo" to "/foo"#
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(?:index\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]
#2)The rule bellow will internally map "/foo" to "/index.php?id=foo"#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Now how can I add a custom parameters name like id2 (or more)?

for example

```
www.example.com/index.php?id=abc --> www.example.com/abc

www.example.com/index.php?id=abc&id2=qaz --> www.example.com/abc/qaz
```

But (here) for this no change:

```
www.example.com/index.php?id=abc&id2=qaz&id3=wsx --> www.example.com/index.php?id=abc&id2=qaz&id3=wsx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another set of rules to handle 2 query parameters:

```
RewriteEngine On

#1A) Redirect "/index.php?id=foo" to "/foo"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(?:index\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]

#1B) Redirect "/index.php?id=foo&id2=bar" to "/foo/bar"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(?:index\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+)&id2=([^\s&]+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [L,R]

# skip all the files and directories from further rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

#2A) The rule bellow will internally map "/foo/bar" to "/index.php?id=foo&id2=bar"
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1&id2=$2 [L,QSA]

#2B) The rule bellow will internally map "/foo" to "/index.php?id=foo"
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```